# Is Wubi safe on Windows Installation?

Tags: wubi, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the benefits of a disk install vs. Wubi? And can I migrate my settings easily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-disk-install-vs-wubi-and-can-i-migrate-my-settings)

Is Wubi installer dangerous? I want to know this before i install it on my laptop. I really want to use Ubuntu OS as my secondary operating system, primary being windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not at all.

As said in [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi):

> The Windows-based Ubuntu Installer (Wubi) allows you to install and uninstall Ubuntu from within Microsoft Windows. **It lets a Microsoft Windows user try Ubuntu without risking any data loss due to disk formatting or partitioning.**

So try it and don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

I've found WUBI most useful in situations like these:
The laptop comes pre-installed with 4 primary partitions, like Manufacturer restore, Windows Preboot, Windows OS and Windows Data. There is no way to add extra partitions for a native Linux install without combining or deleting existing partitions.

WUBI works great in these situations if there is a basic (not dynamic) uncrypted windows partition available. It creates a large file in the windows drive and uses it for storing the linux filesystem.

Also, I've experienced one occasion where Wubi ran just fine for weeks, then wouldn't start anymore after a linux kernel update. Windows would still run just fine. The solution was to boot the computer with an Ubuntu LiveCD and edit the Grub startup file, details are here:
http://tdelphihobbyist.blogspot.com/2010/12/simple-fix-for-my-broken-wubi.html

So, my recommendation would be to primarily install Linux on it's own partition. If that is not possible, by all means use Wubi. It will give you a chance to run Linux without any virtualisation and experience it's versatility and speed first hand.

By default, Wubi uses this chain of booting: MBR -> windows bootloader (choose Ubuntu) -> grub bootloader -> Linux. The default boot OS will be windows, and it can be changed from windows' side My computer properties.

On a native Linux install, the boot goes by default: Grub on MBR -> Linux. You can choose windows from the grub menu, but it's not the default. To change windows to be grub's default boot option, use these commands in Linux terminal:
cd /etc/grub.d
sudo mv 30_os-prober 08_os-prober

Comment: while informative, this information is probably not what the OP was looking for, and is probably more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

While Wubi is an officially supported method of installing Ubuntu within a Windows environment some users have had boot issues after kernel updates.

It is a useful solution if you want to try Ubuntu and uncertain on disk partitioning but ultimately a dual boot installation is a more useful long term solution with updating operating system versions, programs, kernels etc.

An alternative to a Wubi install would be the live CD environment where you can try and test all aspects of an Ubuntu installation BEFORE any installation to your hard drive - this is by far a more useful option if you just want to quickly 'test run' Ubuntu before committing to installing.

Information on Wubi can be found [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu%29) and the [official website](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Ive had no problems using Wubi. Whats great is Windows sees Wubi/Ubuntu as just another program installed on your Windows computer. You are able to delete it any time if you dont need Ubuntu. Some things to consider... I believe a Wubi install can only give you a max of 30GB partition size. You'll find that out after installing Wubi and when setting up Ubuntu using Wubi.

Good luck! Just do all Ubuntu and never look back!

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is a very safe way of trying out Ubuntu because you don't have to partition or mess with bootloaders. There *have* been some booting issues, primarily with 10.04 Lucid Lynx (and upgrades from 10.04 to 10.10) due to some issues with grub updates (grub is the bootloader Ubuntu uses). Fortunately these problems have been solved for the upcoming release Natty Narwhal 11.04, and the fixes will soon be applied to earlier releases as well.

If you want to read about the problems and their solutions, the [Wubi Megathread on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198) is a good place.

Something else you want to note is that Wubi uses a virtual disk (a loopmounted file) so you want to try and avoid hard shutdowns as it can result in corruption. If it appears to be hanging you can usually restart with [Alt+SysRq R-E-I-S-U-B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). Corruption of the root.disk will not affect Windows, but if you end up using Wubi for a while you will need to ensure your data on Ubuntu is kept safe.

You can also review the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it's convenience to use wubi to install ubuntu OS. However it has some problems with hibernate. The OS may not recovery successfully and you may not get into the system again.

Comment: There is little evidence. Have you tested?