# Windows install vs CD/USB install

Tags: system-installation, windows, wubi

I am looking to install ubuntu primarily because I often muck around with my windows system files (authui.dll & ExplorerFrame.dll being the main two) and read that if I happen to corrupt these dll's really badly and can't access them to fix/replace them from the windows OS I can access them from the ubuntu OS. First up is this true?  and if it is, should I install ubuntu using the windows installer or via the CD/USB drive method?

I was reading about the differences between these two options and for the windows installer method one difference stated was that "If your Windows install goes pear-shaped, you may lose access to your Wubi install, too." so from this I'm lead to think that in my case it would pointless to have ubuntu there if I install it through the windows installer, so I should choose the CD/USB option.  Some clarification on the issue would be much appreciated.  Thanks :)

P.S. I'm a really inexperienced user (have never installed ubuntu before or used a dual boot system) so I'm really sorry if the question I asked seems stupid.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What are the benefits of a disk install vs. Wubi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-disk-install-vs-wubi-and-can-i-migrate-my-settings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the benefits of a disk install vs. Wubi? And can I migrate my settings easily?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-disk-install-vs-wubi-and-can-i-migrate-my-settings)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to use Ubuntu. If you don't know how much you want to use Ubuntu, or if you are going to use Windows more often, use the Windows Installer. Ubuntu can easily be uninstalled with the Windows installer, and you don't need to worry about partitioning if you do uninstall it.

If you are sure that you are going to primarily use Ubuntu, but you are still going to use Windows from time to time and you have enough disk space, dual boot. There is less of a risk of Ubuntu damaging your Windows install and Ubuntu will be faster. Also, dual booting is easy. Just click "Install ubuntu alongside Windows" in the installer